# Merge data frames multiple time overwriting NAs resulted in previous merge

Tags: r, merge

I am creating a table on the fly where I have a common date but each iteration adds a column.
The table out come should be

```
date       col1 col2 col3 col4
2016-01-01  1    2   3    4
2016-01-02  11   22  33   44
```

The information that I get is in 4 portions

input1

```
date       col1   col2
2016-01-01 1      2
```

input2

```
date       col1   col2
2016-01-02 11      22
```

input3

```
date       col3   col4
2016-01-01 3      4
```

input4

```
date       col1   col2
2016-01-02 33      44
```

This is the code I wrote but it does not get to the expected result
Instead only the first row is merged while the second row had NA in the merged cells.
NOTE: The amount of columns I will end with is unknown. This is only an example of 2 columns added each time.

```
res=data.frame()
r1= c("2016-01-01",1,2)
names(r1)=c("date","col1","col2")
res=rbind(r1)
#print(res)
r1= c("2016-02-01",11,22)
names(r1)=c("date","col1","col2")
r1_df=data.frame(as.list(r1))
res=merge(res,r1_df,all=T)

r1= c("2016-01-01",3,4)
names(r1)=c("date","col3","col4")
r1_df=data.frame(as.list(r1))
res=merge(res,r1_df,all=T)
r1= c("2016-02-01",33,44)
names(r1)=c("date","col3","col4")
r1_df=data.frame(as.list(r1))
res=merge(res,r1_df,all=T)
print(res)

    date col3 col4 col1 col2
  1 2016-01-01    3    4    1    2
  2 2016-02-01   33   44 <NA> <NA>
  3 2016-02-01 <NA> <NA>   11   22
```

> 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
input1 <- data.frame(date=c("2016-01-01"),col1=1,col2=2,stringsAsFactors = F)
input2 <- data.frame(date=c("2016-01-02"),col1=11,col2=22,stringsAsFactors = F)
input3 <- data.frame(date=c("2016-01-01"),col3=3,col4=4,stringsAsFactors = F)
input4 <- data.frame(date=c("2016-01-02"),col3=33,col4=44,stringsAsFactors = F)

input <-merge(input1,input2,all.x = T,all.y = T)
input0<-merge(input3,input4,all.x = T,all.y = T)
input123 <- merge(input,input0,all.x=T)
print(input123)
        date col1 col2 col3 col4
1 2016-01-01    1    2    3    4
2 2016-01-02   11   22   33   44
```

Comment: Your answer asuumes I know what each input has and I gather them in a specific way. My problem is that I can not match the inputs to decide how to organize them. The input pieces  come in arbitrarily. I merge each one as it appears to the last merge.